# Avoid a recurring loop that repeats an instruction every time it reaches the end

Tags: python, while-loop, repeat

My problem is, my rock, paper, scissors program seems trapped in a loop somewhere. I suspect it's either the inner loop that asks the user for the number of rounds, or the outer loop that asks the user how many players should play; both might even have indentation problems but I am not sure.

```
import random
from os import system, name
from time import sleep
#variable declarations and initializations
computer,players, rounds, wins, loses, draws, yourPlay, count, rec, playerRange =  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3

#function definitions
def RoundsWonResult():
    print ("You played:",playerMoves[yourPlay])
    print ("The computer played:",playerMoves[computer])
    print (playerMoves[yourPlay] + " beats " + playerMoves[computer] +"!")
    print ("You win!")
    return
def RoundsLostResult():
    print ("You played:",playerMoves[yourPlay])
    print ("The computer played:",playerMoves[computer])
    print (playerMoves[computer] + " beats " + playerMoves[yourPlay] +"!")
    print ("You lose!")
    return    
def DrawMatch():
    global draws
    while (yourPlay == computer):
        print ("You played:",playerMoves[yourPlay])
        print ("The computer played:",playerMoves[computer])
        print ("It's a draw!")
        draws+=1
        return
def WinsMatch():
    global wins
    while (yourPlay != computer):
        if (yourPlay == 0 and computer != 1):
            if (computer == 2):
                RoundsWonResult()
                wins+=1
        elif (yourPlay == 1 and computer == 0):
            if (computer != 2):
                RoundsWonResult()
                wins+=1
        elif (yourPlay == 2 and computer != 0):
            if (computer == 1):
                RoundsWonResult()
                wins+=1          
        return
def LosesMatch():
    global loses
    while (yourPlay != computer):
        if (yourPlay == 0 and computer == 1):
            if (computer != 2):
                RoundsLostResult()
                loses+=1
        elif (yourPlay == 1 and computer == 2):
            if (computer != 0):
                RoundsLostResult()
                loses+=1
        elif (yourPlay == 2 and computer == 0):
            if (computer != 1):
                RoundsLostResult()
                loses+=1 
        return
try:
    players = int(input("Enter number of players[1-3]:"))
    while (players < 1 or players > playerRange):
        print ("Invalid range selected!")
        players = int(input("Enter number of players[1-3]:"))
except ValueError:
        print ("Only numeric values are allowed!")
        players = int(input("Enter number of players[1-3]:"))        
if (players > 0 and players <= 3):
    print ("Good luck to all " + str(players) + " of you. May the better player win!")
while (rec < players):
    try:
        rounds = int (input("Enter number of rounds to play:"))
        while (rounds <= 0):
            print ("Value must be greater than zero!")
            rounds = int (input("Enter number of rounds to play:"))
            print(rec)
            print(rounds)
    except ValueError:
            print ("Only numeric values are allowed!")
            rounds = int (input("Enter number of rounds to play:"))            
            if (rounds != "" and rounds > 0):
                print ("Let the games begin!")
    else:
        print ("Rock beats Scissors, Scissors beats Paper, and Paper beats Rock. Good Luck!")
        print("You entered " + str(rounds) + " round(s)!")
        playerMoves = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
        while (count < rounds):
            try:
                yourPlay = int(input("(0)Rock,(1)Paper,(2)Scissors:"))
                while (yourPlay < 0 or yourPlay > 2):
                    print ("Invalid selection!")
                    yourPlay = int(input("(0)Rock,(1)Paper,(2)Scissors:"))
            except ValueError:
                print ("Only numeric values are allowed!")
                yourPlay = int(input("(0)Rock,(1)Paper,(2)Scissors:"))
            else:
                computer = random.randint(0,2) #randomizes the numbers  0 - 2
            if (yourPlay == computer):
                DrawMatch()
            elif (yourPlay != computer):
                WinsMatch()
                LosesMatch() 
            count+=1
            print ("End of Round ", count)
            if (count == rounds):
                print ("Wins:",wins)
                print ("Loses:",loses)
                print ("Draws:",draws) 
                #resultLog = {"Wins":wins,"Loses":loses,"Draws":draws}
                fileName = input("Enter Your name: ")
                #print (resultLog)   
                with open (fileName,"w") as plyrRec:
                    print ("Your file has been created!")
                    plyrRec.close()
                with open (fileName, "a") as plyrRec:
                    plyrRec.write ("{}{}\n{}{}\n{}{}\n".format("Wins:",wins,"Loses:",loses,"Draws:",draws))
                    plyrRec.close()
                    rec+=1
                    print ("End of Record ", rec)
```

So the code works fairly well except that at the end of the first round it repeatedly asks the user to enter number of rounds to play. I hope someone can advise me please.

Comment: Whats the value of rec and players when the the player is asked to enter number of rounds to play? Your problem may be due to this line: `while (rec < players):`

Comment: Please cut out the useless "junk" and provide a [mcve] to maximize your chances of getting an answer... Few people are willing to debug through 100s of lines for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Date first created: September 6, 2018 v.0
#Version: v.1, modified 2021/08/31
#This is a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. 
#Rock beats scissors, scissors beats paper, and paper beats rock.

import random

#variable declaration and initialization
game_moves = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]

def is_input_numeric(str_val):
    '''(string) -> bool
    Returns whether a string input contains ONLY numeric values greater than zero
    >>> is_input_numeric('4')
    True
    >>> is_input_numeric("like 7")
    False  
    '''
    return str_val.isnumeric() and int(str_val) > 0 and int(str_val) <= 20

def is_input_numeric_range(str_val):
    '''(string) -> bool
    Returns whether a string input contains ONLY a numeric value greater than zero but less than
    or equal to two
    >>> is_input_numeric_range('y')
    False
    >>> is_input_numeric_range('3')
    False
    >>> is_input_numeric_range('2')
    True
    '''
    return str_val.isnumeric() and int(str_val) >= 0 and int(str_val) <= 2
            

def validate_rounds():
    '''(string) -> string
    checks str_val and passes control to is_input_numeric function, then returns a string value
    >>> validate_rounds() -> is_input_numeric("time")
    False
    >>> validate_rounds() -> is_input_numeric('0')
    False
     >>> validate_rounds()-> is_input_numeric('10')
     True
    '''
    valid_rounds = False
    while not valid_rounds:
        rounds = input("Enter number of rounds to play[min = 1, max = 20]: ")
        valid_rounds = is_input_numeric(rounds)
    return rounds
     
def validate_player_input():
    '''(string) -> string
    checks string and passes control to is_input_numeric_range function, then returns the string value
    >>> validate_player_input() -> is_input_numeric_range('-1')
    False
    >>> validate_player_input() -> is_input_numeric_range('i')
    False
    >>> validate_player_input() -> is_input_numeric_range('3')
    False
    >>> validate_player_input() -> is_input_numeric_range('0')
    True
    '''
    valid_player_control = False
    while not valid_player_control:
        player_move = input("ONLY (0)Rock,(1)Paper,(2)Scissors, allowed: ")
        valid_player_control = is_input_numeric_range(player_move)
    return player_move

def get_computer_play():
    '''Returns a whole number in the range 0:2
    '''
    computer_move = random.randint(0,2)
    return computer_move
    

def human_player_wins(plyr, comp):
    wins = 0
    rock_beats_scissors = False
    paper_beats_rock = False
    scissors_beats_paper = False
    human_hand = plyr
    computer_hand = comp
    if human_hand == 0 and computer_hand == 2:
        rock_beats_scissors = True
    elif human_hand == 1 and computer_hand == 0:
        paper_beats_rock = True
    elif human_hand == 2 and computer_hand == 1:
        scissors_beats_paper = True
    if rock_beats_scissors  or paper_beats_rock or scissors_beats_paper:
        print(game_moves[human_hand] +  " beats " + game_moves[computer_hand] + "!")
        print("You Win!")
        wins += 1
    return wins

                
def human_player_lose(plyr, comp):
    lose = 0
    rock_beats_scissors = False
    paper_beats_rock = False
    scissors_beats_paper = False
    human_hand = plyr
    computer_hand = comp
    if human_hand == 0 and computer_hand == 1:
        paper_beats_rock = True
    elif human_hand == 1 and computer_hand == 2:
        scissors_beats_paper = True
    elif human_hand == 2 and computer_hand == 0:
        rock_beats_scissors = True
    if rock_beats_scissors  or paper_beats_rock or scissors_beats_paper:
        print(game_moves[computer_hand] +  " beats " + game_moves[human_hand] + "!")
        print("You Lose!")
        lose += 1
    return lose

    
def players_draw():
    draws = 0
    print("It's a draw!")
    draws += 1
    return draws
    

def start_game():
    rounds_played = 0
    total_wins = 0
    total_losses = 0
    total_draws = 0
    highest_score = 0

    game_rounds = input("Enter number of rounds to play[Max = 20]: ")
    rounds_valid = is_input_numeric(game_rounds)
    if not rounds_valid:
        game_rounds = validate_rounds()
        
    while rounds_played < int(game_rounds):
        player_hand = input("(0)Rock,(1)Paper,(2)Scissors: ")
        valid_control  = is_input_numeric_range(player_hand)
        print('plyr:', player_hand)
        if not valid_control:
            player_hand = validate_player_input()
        computer_hand = get_computer_play()
        print('comp:', computer_hand)
        if int(player_hand) == computer_hand:
            total_draws += players_draw()
        if int(player_hand) != computer_hand:
            total_wins += human_player_wins(int(player_hand),computer_hand)
            total_losses += human_player_lose(int(player_hand),computer_hand)
        rounds_played += 1
        
    if total_wins > highest_score:
        highest_score = total_wins * 10
    print('\n--------------------------GAME RESULTS--------------------------')
    print('\nHigh Score = ', highest_score )
    print('\nrounds played = ', rounds_played, '||','wins = ', total_wins,'||', 'losses = ', total_losses, '||','draws = ', total_draws )
    print('\n--------------------------END OF RESULTS------------------------')
     
    

start_game()
```

Thanks to those who tried to helped me it was appreciated. This is the new version now after four years. Yikes!

Comment: Consider marking this answer as correct by pressing the checkmark. Also, it would be helpful for others if you describe the exact solution, next to the new code version.